# Webkit browsers are very slow

Tags: google-chrome, browser, opera, webkit

Weird behavior here.

I'm on Windows 8, and both Chrome and the new Opera (the new, new one, Webkit based) are very slow loading new pages and tabs. When I start a new tab in chrome it takes a few seconds to see the starting page, navigating to new websites takes ages - but when I reach the websites, I can navigate on that domain just fine without any slow downs.

IE and Firefox run fine, it's not my internet :).

I have checked for faulty extensions, turned everything off, tried incognito windows too - same result, initial page loads take several seconds to load (5-10 seconds on EVERY page).

The hell is wrong Webkit?

Comment: Technically, these are Blink, not WebKit. Google forked it because in effect, webkit was already forked.

Answer (score 1):

It was a piece of garbage software (malware?) called Browser Defender.